# each group by in list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

in `List<file>` i have data :

```
id   Initial         B
 1      G       (2016-27-12)
 2      H       (2016-27-15)
 3      G       (2016-27-16)

//my code
List<file> i = new List<file>;

var r = i.Select(i=> i.Initial).GroupBy(x => new { r = x.to List() });

for( int i = 0; i < r.Count(); i++ )
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(r[i].ToString());
}
```

but my code still error.

how to `GroupBy()` with `linq` and each Initial result 2 count value G & H?

Comment: before fixing them, what the error message actually says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var r = i.Select(i=> i.Initial).GroupBy(x =>x).ToList();
```

Other way with [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 var r = i.Select(i=> i.Initial).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if thats what you are trying to do but to me it looks like you want to get every unique Initial from your list. To accomplish that, you can use "Distinct":

```
var r = i.Select(i=> i.Initial).Distinct();
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, please provide more info.